# Moving Next Column In DataGridView automatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have following code where I need execution to go to next column IF condition is met.
Please help.

```
 Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If i >= 0 Then
        Service_Reservation.TxtBoxResID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        Service_Reservation.txtBoxSerID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        Service_Reservation.DatePickerDateIn.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        If DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value Is Nothing Then
            ****
        Else
            Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerDateOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        End If
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerTimeIn.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerTimeOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
        Service_Reservation.txtBoxQty.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
```

Comment: If you are relying on a variable (`i`) for the rows, why not doing the same thing with the columns, rather than hardcoding the values (e.g., `i2` whose value you might change inside the condition)? In any case, this question is too basic to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be searching for a way for simplified syntax for a test for an object that is not nothing. .Net added IsNot at some point which avoids clumsy coding:

```
    If DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value IsNot Nothing Then
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerDateOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    End If
    'clumsy way but valid
    If Not DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value Is Nothing Then
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerDateOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    End If
```

---

An empty IF or ELSE portion is OK - sometimes makes the code more readable

```
    If DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value Is Nothing Then
        ' *** probably bad data - see Fred
    Else
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerDateOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    End If
```

Note you can use column names to address cells (unless you used the IDE to create the dataobjects.)

```
    If DataGridView1.Item("Reservation_Date", i).Value Is Nothing Then
        ****
    Else
        Service_Reservation.DateTimePickerDateOut.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    End If
```